# vba filling table range error Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

On sheet 'Work' I have a table:

```
Set tbl = Work.ListObjects("CaseData")
lastWork = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
```

Now I am trying to fill a range within the table. I am able to do that without referring to the table this way:

```
Work.Range("A2:A" & lastWork) = 10
```

However, the following does not work:

```
tbl.Range("A2:A" & lastWork).Value = 10
```

I am getting an error: Invalid procedure call or argument.
How would I fill a column within a table?
And is it possible to do that referring to the column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to the column by name:

```
tbl.ListColumns("ColumnName").DataBodyRange.Value = 10
```

You can also refer to it by index:

```
tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value = 10
```